# Using Saved Game Service for non-game apps

Tags: android, google-play-games, android-backup-service

I have an android (non-game) app that I want to implement cloud backup for.  I've looked at the [Backup API](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html) but found it limited as the actual backup and restore backend processes are controlled by the phone manufacture and Google. I also want to allow the user to manually backup and restore when they want.

There is the new [Google Play Games Saved Game service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) which offers what I'm looking for but my app is not a game.

Has anyone implemented the Saved Game service for a non-game app and can offer some advice on it's suitability?  Otherwise, does anyone know whether Google will allow this approach (using the game service for non-game app)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a better solution would be to use the Google Drive API.  Specifically, the ability to store application data. From the developer doc:

> The 'Application Data folder' is a special folder that is only
>   accessible by your application. Its content is hidden from the user,
>   and from other apps. Despite being hidden from the user, the
>   Application Data folder is stored on the user's Drive and therefore
>   uses the user's Drive storage quota. The Application Data folder can
>   be used to store configuration files, saved games data, or any other
>   types of files that the user should not tamper with.

See: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata